# PayUmoney payment gateway integration won't accept amount var to be nothing but an input field

Tags: php, html, payment-gateway, payumoney

I'm trying to make a payment gateway integration, however, although I did everything, except I need the amount var value to be passed as a radio button field, but it is only accepting it as with input field. which makes a big problem here. Please go through the code I tried so far.

Don't worry about the merchant id or hash key.

I tried to add the amount field as radio button but it won't accept, but when added as input field it is accepting.

```
<?php

$MERCHANT_KEY = "####";
$SALT = "####";

$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://secure.payu.in";

$action = '';

$posted = array();
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    //print_r($_POST);
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {    
    $posted[$key] = $value; 

  }
}

$formError = 0;

if(empty($posted['txnid'])) {
  // Generate random transaction id
  $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
} else {
  $txnid = $posted['txnid'];
}
$hash = '';
// Hash Sequence
$hashSequence ="key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
if(empty($posted['hash']) && sizeof($posted) > 0) {
   if(
          empty($posted['key'])
          || empty($posted['txnid'])
           || empty($posted['amount'])
          || empty($posted['firstname'])
          || empty($posted['email'])
          || empty($posted['phone'])
          || empty($posted['productinfo'])
          || empty($posted['surl'])
          || empty($posted['furl'])
          || empty($posted['service_provider'])
  ) {
    $formError = 1;
  } else {
    //$posted['productinfo'] = json_encode(json_decode('[{"name":"tutionfee","description":"","value":"500","isRequired":"false"},{"name":"developmentfee","description":"monthly tution fee","value":"1500","isRequired":"false"}]'));
$hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);
$hash_string = '';  
foreach($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var) {
  $hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
  $hash_string .= '|';
}

$hash_string .= $SALT;


$hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));
$action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
  }
} elseif(!empty($posted['hash'])) {
  $hash = $posted['hash'];
  $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
}
 ?>
<script>
   var hash = '<?php echo $hash ?>';
    function submitPayuForm() {
     if(hash == '') {
       return;
      }
      var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
      payuForm.submit();
    }
  </script>

 <body onload="submitPayuForm()">

<?php if($formError) { ?>

      <span style="color:red">Please fill all mandatory fields.</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    <?php } ?>


<section style="padding-top:50px;padding-bottom:50px"class="section-padding banner-6 parallax-bg bg-fixed overlay light-9" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center mb-80">
         <h2 class="section-title text-uppercase"><u style="text-decoration: none;border-bottom: 1px solid #673ab7;border-top: 1px solid #673ab7;border-right: 1px solid #673ab7;border-left: 1px solid #673ab7;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;">&nbsp &nbsp Register Here &nbsp&nbsp</u></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="
     border-top-color: #673ab7;
     border-right-color: #673ab7;
     border-bottom-color:#673ab7;
     border-left-color: #673ab7;
     border-width:1px;
     border-style: solid;
     text-align:center;">
         <div class="col-md-3"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6" >
            <form name="payuForm" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" name="payuForm">

            <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $MERCHANT_KEY ?>" />
              <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid ?>" />






            <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" />

               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="input-field">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Username/Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['email'])) ? '' : $posted['email']; ?>" class="validate">
                        <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Email</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['password'])) ? '' : $posted['password']; ?>" class="validate" id="name">
                        <label for="name">Password</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['firstname'])) ? '' : $posted['firstname']; ?>" class="validate">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="input-field">
                        <input name="phone" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['phone'])) ? '' : $posted['phone']; ?>" type="tel"  class="validate">
                         <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="input-field">
                        <input id="phone" type="tel" name="productinfo" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['productinfo'])) ? '' : $posted['productinfo'] ?>" class="validate">
                        <label for="phone">Your Profession</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="input-field">
                        <input id="website" type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['address'])) ? '' : $posted['address']; ?>" class="validate">
                        <label for="website">Address</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>






               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                     <center>
                        <div class="input-field">
                           <input id="sedan" type="radio"  value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount'] ?>1"  name="amount" >Sedan
                           <label for="sedan">.</label>
                        </div>
                     </center>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                     <center>
                        <div class="input-field">
                           <input id="suv" type="radio"  value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount'] ?>1" name="amount" >SUV
                       <label for="suv">.</label>
                        </div>
                     </center>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                     <center>
                        <div class="input-field">
                           <input id="sedansuv" type="radio" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount'] ?>2" name="amount" >Both
                           <label for="sedansuv">.</label>
                        </div>
                     </center>
                  </div>
               </div>

                <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <center>
                        <div class="input-field" id="sedanonly">

                           <input name="amount" type="text" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount'] ?>" />
                           <label for="sedan">Total (in Rupees)</label>
                        </div>



                     </center>
                  </div>
               </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" name="surl" readonly value="http://sgdcontest.com/success.php" size="64" />
                        <label for="phone">For Office Use Only</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" name="furl" readonly value="http://sgdcontest.com/failure.php" size="64" />
                        <label for="website">For Office Use Only</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>


               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                     <center>
                     <?php if(!$hash) { ?>
                        <button type="submit" style="width:140px"name="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn  pink mt-30" value="Submit" />Register</button>
                    <?php } ?>
                     </center>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>`
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you pass information in radio or input text as soon as the price is submitted in valid accepted format.

Comment: you see those radio buttons named as amount..? they are not being accepted while the input box below is being accepted.

Comment: According to your condition - value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount'] ?>1", you are passing amount+1 in your finally submitted values, confirm your passed values by printing $_POST

Comment: If you have more than one same name `input fields` then it will always return last field value in post. So you must have to change `radio button name attribute`.